Mecanismo para la conservacion de modelos visuales basados en HTML+Javascript (plugin)
Cuando se pretende recrear un elemento que tiene asociado/inicializado un plugin de diseño, lo recomendado es destruirlo/desvincularlo, y cada vez que creas el elemento inicializarlo nuevamente. normalmente esto ocurre cuando se implementa SPA y se carga contenido mediante AJAX
Ejemplo:
https://datatables.net/manual/
var table = new DataTable('#myTable');

y luego lo destruimos con:
table.destroy();

Esta mecanica se practica alrededor de diferentes plugins: como Select2, Dropzone y cada una tiene sus metodo especificos... Esto es funcional a pequeña escala (desarrollos pequeños).
Estoy buscando una solucion a gran escala (para implementar en una plataforma), no conozco un mecanismo de automatizacion que se encargue en javascript de preservar los plugin aunque el elemento cambie su contenido y/o un mecanismo estandar para que se automatice el ciclo de vida de los elementos en el DOM o que fueron agregados.
Tener que reprogramar por cada elemento estas funcionalidades me parece que no es escalable. esto esta relacionado a los flujos de control de las funcionalidades agregadas a un sistema.

Auto respuesta:
El principal papel de trabajar en la programación en un sistema/plataforma/framework, es establecer ciertos códigos que faciliten el despliegue de elementos.
Vamos a hacer una clase que se encargue de registrar los plugin y de materializar su construcción y destrucción:
class PluginManager {
  constructor() {
    this.plugins = {};
  }
  register(selector, pluginInit, pluginDestroy) {
    this.plugins[selector] = {
      init: pluginInit,
      destroy: pluginDestroy,
      instance: null
    };
  }

  init(selector) {
    if (this.plugins[selector]) {
      if (this.plugins[selector].instance) {
        this.plugins[selector].destroy(this.plugins[selector].instance);
      }
      this.plugins[selector].instance = this.plugins[selector].init(document.querySelector(selector));
    }
  }
  destroy(selector) {
    if (this.plugins[selector] && this.plugins[selector].instance) {
      this.plugins[selector].destroy(this.plugins[selector].instance);
      this.plugins[selector].instance = null;
    }
  }
  reinit(selector) {
    this.destroy(selector);
    this.init(selector);
  }
}

const pluginManager = new PluginManager();

Luego los registros:
// DataTable
pluginManager.register(
  '#myTable',
  (element) => new DataTable(element),
  (instance) => instance.destroy()
);

// Select2
pluginManager.register(
  '.select2',
  (element) => $(element).select2(),
  (instance) => $(instance).select2('destroy')
);

// Dropzone
pluginManager.register(
  '#myDropzone',
  (element) => new Dropzone(element),
  (instance) => instance.destroy()
);

Ahora podemos inicializar de esta forma los plugins:
function initializeAllPlugins() {
  for (let selector in pluginManager.plugins) {
    pluginManager.init(selector);
  }
}

// Llamar a esta función cuando sea necesario inicializar todos los plugins
initializeAllPlugins();

Nota: esto es importante ejecutarlo en cada carga de pantalla...
Monitorear Cambios en el DOM.
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          for (let selector in pluginManager.plugins) {
            if (node.matches(selector) || node.querySelector(selector)) {
              pluginManager.reinit(selector);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// Inicializar los plugins la primera vez
initializeAllPlugins();

Observaciones Generales:
Lo importante es la interacción de la clase en donde tenemos: register, init, destroy, reinit como unas instancias automatizadas que manejaran el ciclo de vida de los elementos... .

Ahora podemos ir un poco más profundos he hilar sobre los parámetros que queremos pasar a los plugins:
Ejemplo de parámetros:
<table id="myTable" data-params="attoolset:true,atpaging:true,atordering:true,atinfo:true,atsearching:true,atautoWidth:true,atscrollCollapse:false,atresponsive:true,atscrollY:400px,atscrollX:true"></table>

Cambios en el init:
  init(selector, params = {}) {
    if (this.plugins[selector]) {
      if (this.plugins[selector].instance) {
        this.plugins[selector].destroy(this.plugins[selector].instance);
      }
      this.plugins[selector].instance = this.plugins[selector].init(document.querySelector(selector), params);
    }
  }

Registrar con los parámetros:
pluginManager.register(
  '#myTable',
  (element, params) => {
    const defaultParams = {
      paging: true,
      ordering: true,
      info: true,
      searching: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      scrollCollapse: false,
      responsive: false,
      scrollY: false,
      scrollX: false,
      noSearch: false
    };
        
    // Combina parámetros por defecto con parámetros adicionales
    const options = Object.assign({}, defaultParams, params);
        
    return $(element).DataTable({
      dom: options.attoolset || 'lfrtip',
      paging: options.atpaging,
      pageLength: options.atregdisplay,
      ordering: options.atordering,
      info: options.atinfo,
      searching: options.atsearching,
      autoWidth: options.atautoWidth,
      scrollCollapse: options.atscrollCollapse,
      responsive: options.atresponsive,
      scrollY: options.atscrollY,
      scrollX: options.atscrollX
    });
  },
  (instance) => instance.destroy()
);

Parsear parámetros:
function parseParams(dataParams) {
  if (!dataParams) return {};
  const params = {};
  dataParams.split(',').forEach(param => {
    const [key, value] = param.split(':');
    params[key.trim()] = (value.trim() === 'true') ? 
        true
      :
        (value.trim() === 'false') ? false : value.trim();
  });
  return params;
}

El Inicializador:
function initializeDataTable(selector) {
  const target = $(selector);
  const dataParams = target.attr("data-params");
  const params = parseParams(dataParams);
    
  pluginManager.init(selector, params);
}

// Inicializar DataTables con parámetros personalizados
initializeDataTable('#myTable');

Por último el Observador del DOM:
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          for (let selector in pluginManager.plugins) {
            if (node.matches(selector) || node.querySelector(selector)) {
              initializeDataTable(selector);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// Inicializar los plugins la primera vez
initializeDataTable('#myTable');

